# Exibir api com Ionic

Tags: api, ionic, typescript

Boa Tarde a todos, estou consumindo uma api, porém não consigo exibi-la no meu template, ela esta sendo consumida, aparece no console, porém não consigo no template.

Component :

```
import { PaisesProvider } from './../../providers/paises/paises';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  cotacao: string [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private paisesProvider: PaisesProvider) {


  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.listaCotacao();  

  }

  listaCotacao() {
    this.paisesProvider.listaPaises()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.cotacao = data;
      console.log(this.cotacao);

    });
  }
}

Template: 

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

    <ion-item  *ngFor="let c of cotacao">
      Data : {{c.date}} Valor Compra {{c.buy}} Valor Venda {{c.sell}}    
    </ion-item>          

</ion-content>
```

Aparece o erro :

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Nessa linha `Data : {{c.date}} Valor Compra {{c.buy}} Valor Venda {{c.sell}}  ` você está dizendo que no seu array existe um objeto com as propriedades buy, sell e date. Como é a resposta de `console.log(this.cotacao);`?  Talvez basta trocar seu array de cotações para  `cotacao: string [{ }]}}`;

Comment: Esta assim amigo : 

{"ticker": {"high": "29399.00000000", "low": "28234.00000000", "vol": "126.05166124", "last": "29000.12224000", "buy": "29000.13024000", "sell": "29282.98250000", "date": 1535741070}}

Comment: Notou que isso é um objeto javascript e não um array?

Comment: Você está usando TypeScript ou Javascript?

Comment: Notei sim. Estou usando TypeScript

Comment: Você itera com `ngFor` sobre um array

Answer (score 0):

Você está dando um `*ngFor` em alguma resposta que não é um array, é disso que ele está reclamando, ele está vindo como objeto. Se você quiser exibir os campos desse objeto.

No caso dessa response aí que você informou, ele é um objeto, logo não precisa percorrer os valores dele, basta acessá-los diretamente como por exemplo:
`c.date` `c.buy`  e assim por diante.

Comment: Exato, é um array super simples , mas nao consigo exibir.

Comment: Segue api: https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/BTC/ticker/ . 

Eu não estou conseguindo exibir no template de jeito nenhum

Comment: Ela não parece  ser um vetor mas como vou exibi - la no template ?

Comment: Nesse caso você não precisa dar um ngFor, basta dar um `c.ticker.date` `c.ticker.buy` e assim por diante.